# RTSP/RTP commands to wrong port number - should they be honoured?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, rtsp, rtp

I'm hoping someone here can save me from having to dive into the RTSP standards to prove a point...

Basically I'm tracking a bug whereby a streaming client sets up an RTSP stream from Port 554 but then sends subsequent control commands to a *different* port (which happens to also be an RTSP streaming port, but a different stream / Session ID) to keep the stream alive.

Perhaps unsurprisingly, the command response is `Stream Not Found` and the client drops the stream.

It looks to me like the client software is opening the two streams (`rtsp://<ip_address>:554/0` and `rtsp://<ip_address>:8554/1`), failing to properly track which port/session is which and sending the wrong thing to the wrong port.

So, if it starts session A on `rtsp://<ip_address>:554/0` and session B on `rtsp://<ip_address>:8554/1`, but then sends `OPTIONS Session ID A` to `rtsp://<ip_address>:8554` it fails.

I'm pretty sure this behaviour is wrong - although it would be *possible* for our server to "look up" the session ID that arrives on the "wrong" port and route the command to the correct session, this feels like a bad idea and not expected or valid behaviour.

So, can anyone tell me if I'm right or wrong here?